# Как избавиться от отступа слева у первой буквы заголовка?

Tags: html, css

Господа, вопрос возможно глупый и недостойный вашего внимания, но мне непонятный. Существует ли какая-либо возможность избавиться от отступа (не маргины и паддинги, а именно ширина буквы), который показан на скрине? Там буквально 2 пикселя, но картину портит. Использовать отрицательный маргин для заголовка неохота, может есть альтернативный вариант?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2, p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Free iOS Business Apps</h2>
  <p>ipsum lorem</p>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем примере (в "Выполнить код") все нормально без двух пикселей - но там и шрифт другой, с засечками, которые как раз занимают эти 2 пикселя.

Comment: Посмотрите на выравнивание заголовка относительно нижней строки по левой стороне. Если так не заметно - сделайте скрин,  и откройте в фотошопе, а выставив линейки увидите, что отступ все-же есть. Отступ не самого заголовка, не h2, а у его первой буквы.

Comment: Шрифт, что на прикрепленном скрине, что в моем коде одинаков - Open Sans. Сейчас подключу его через Google Fonts, он у вас видимо не установлен в системе.

Comment: Это не проблема, это сам шрифт такой. Скачайте и установите себе в ОС и увидите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ситуация с заголовком - классический случай, когда нужно использовать ручной кёрнинг. Универсального средства тут нет. Этот "отступ" был бы менее заметен, если бы сразу под заголовком не было бы текста с сильно меньшим кеглем. И даже, если бы первая буква следующей строчки была бы буквой "O" вы бы эту проблему не обнаружили.

Comment: Под ручным кёрнингом вы подразумеваете font-kerning? Увы, я обладаю не самым богатым опытом работы в верстке, поэтому не совсем понял, о чем идет речь в первом предложении вашего ответа.

Comment: Может я не совсем точно выразился. Я имел в виду, что в данном случае единственный способ - вручную подгонять положение первых букв в этих двух строчках. Это можно делать играясь со свойством text-indent (возможны отрицательные значения) в обеих строчках.